# Visual Studio 2015 different version number causes solution file to be checked out

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, solution

I am not sure if that is something generic or our project specific issue.  we have mvc application and I recognized the other day that every time I open the solution VS 2015 update 2 checking out the solution. when I compare the difference /change, I see that it is the Visual Studio Version as below in the screenshot.

[image]

This is because my colleague had lower version number. But I wonder why VS checks out the solution when the version numbers are different? It doesn't even happen when I open the same project with VS 2013.

TFS version is 2012 running on TFSVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the solution using a another version, it will update the version accordingly. This would be to ensure that if functionality were not backward compatible, other users would get a warning if the tried to open using an older version.

This also happens with database projects when you update SSDT.

As you are running the same major version, it should not be an issue even if you checked in the change.

Comment: by older version do you mean the same version with older version number or like 2013-2015 because between 2013-2015 i cant reproduce this is happening only for the same version as 2015 but different version number.